# Using two counters in a loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, tkinter

I have been making a text based game at home using Python and have been having trouble with creating a small section of combat between the player and a foe. The combat is supposed to include two random rolls; one for the player and one for the alien. If the alien rolls higher than the player then +1 should be added to the alien_wins counter and if the player wins +1 should be added to the player_wins counter.

What I want to happen is when the player_wins counter reaches 3 the loop will stop and produce a message, the same should also happen when the alien_ wins reaches 3 but I have had trouble making that work. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
import random
from Tkinter import *

def Fight():

    player_wins = 0
    alien_wins = 0

    while player_wins <= 3:

        player_roll = random.randint(0, 10)
        alien_roll = random.randint(0, 7)

        if player_roll > alien_roll:
            contents.set("You manage to fire a shot of your laser pistol and the alien backs off.")
            player_wins += 1
            return

        elif alien_roll > player_roll:
            contents.set("The alien reaches out and strikes you with its claws.")
            alien_wins += 1
            return

        elif alien_roll == player_roll:
            contents.set("You both grapple eachother and eventually back off.")        
            return

            if player_wins == 3:
                contents.set("You manage to overcome the alien. It leaps from wall to wall and crawls into the vents.")
                win = True
                break
            elif alien_wins == 3:
                contents.set("You lose the fight to the alien. Game Over!")
                break

base = Tk()

contents = StringVar()
display = Message(base, textvariable = contents, relief=RAISED)
display.pack()

enterbutton = Button(base, text = 'Try Again', command = Fight).pack()

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, you want to continue looping while ```player_wins <= 3``` and ```alien_wins  <= 3```?

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you `return` during the first iteration? Also, why is there code after a `return` (in the `alien_roll == player_roll` branch)?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I want it to loop through until one of the two reaches 3 and then produce a message.

Comment: Sorry that bit of code afterwards I was unsure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to continue fighting (looping) while either condition (points <= 3) is `True`.  You need to add another condition to the `while` loop.

You only want to return from the function after the fighting is over so remove all of those returns and add one that is outside of the loop after the fighting is over.  Also, you only want to create the messages after the fighting is over.

```
def Fight():

    player_wins = 0
    alien_wins = 0

    while player_wins <= 3 and alien_wins <= 3:

        player_roll = random.randint(0, 10)
        alien_roll = random.randint(0, 7)

        if player_roll > alien_roll:
            contents.set("You manage to fire a shot of your laser pistol and the alien backs off.")
            player_wins += 1

        elif alien_roll > player_roll:
            contents.set("The alien reaches out and strikes you with its claws.")
            alien_wins += 1

        elif alien_roll == player_roll:
            contents.set("You both grapple eachother and eventually back off.")        

    if player_wins == 3:
        contents.set("You manage to overcome the alien. It leaps from wall to wall and crawls into the vents.")
        win = True
    elif alien_wins == 3:
        contents.set("You lose the fight to the alien. Game Over!")
    return
```

Comment: It helps to write down in words what you are trying to accomplish, then look at what you wrote and look for *chunks of functionality* and maybe reorganize the words along those chunks, then convert those chunks into statements or functions or other things. *Those words* can also help document your code so when you look at it a month from now you'll understand what you did or were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up a few things. Your main problem of looping was fixed by making the loop dependent on both `player_wins` and `alien_wins` being `<= 3`. This way, whenever one of them hits `3`, the loop terminates, and control goes to the following `if/else` statement which will then set the winner.

```
def Fight():    
    player_wins = 0
    alien_wins = 0

    while player_wins <= 3 and alien_wins <= 3:    
        player_roll = random.randint(0, 10)
        alien_roll = random.randint(0, 7)

        if player_roll > alien_roll:
            contents.set("You manage to fire a shot of your laser pistol and the alien backs off.")
            player_wins += 1
        elif alien_roll > player_roll:
            contents.set("The alien reaches out and strikes you with its claws.")
            alien_wins += 1
        else:
            contents.set("You both grapple eachother and eventually back off.")     

    if player_wins == 3:
        contents.set("You manage to overcome the alien. It leaps from wall to wall and crawls into the vents.")
        win = True
    else:
        contents.set("You lose the fight to the alien. Game Over!")
```

You also didn't need those `break` statements, as that was breaking out of the loop entirely. You probably were thinking of `continue`, which will just go to the next iteration of the loop, however even that isn't needed since the entire contents of the loop is just an `if/else` statement, so only one branch will execute.

Also, the `elif` where you checked for the two `rolls` being equal was unnecessary, since you already ruled out that neither is greater/less than the other, so it can be assumed they're equal. Same goes for the final `if/else` where you check for who has `3`. If we are out of the loop, we know somebody has `3`, so we only need to actually check a single players score.